# Docker: Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version on initial setup behind corporate proxy

Tags: macos, ssl, docker, proxy, docker-machine

I installed DockerToolbox-1.11.2 on Mac ElCapitan. When i try to run the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" i get an error as below

> Running pre-create checks... (default) Unable to get the latest
> Boot2Docker ISO release version: Get
> https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority Creating machine...
> (default) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:
> Get
> https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

But it seem to have created the VM.

When i run any docker command it ends up with a timeout error.

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get
> https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.23/containers/json: Gateway Timeout

But when i try to run "docker run" on docker-machine it gives the same error as the initial one.

> docker@default:~$ docker run hello-world
>
> Unable to find image'hello-world:latest' locally
>
> Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
>
> docker: Error while pulling image: Get
> https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images:
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
>
> See 'docker run --help'.

I guess the issue is related to proxy certificates, tried searching for a solution to this issue but have not found any yet.

Will appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: The client can not validate that the server is who it says it is. You client typically should come with a set of root certificate signing authorities. So your client trusts those authorities who sign others that they trust creating a chain of trust which should eventually validate the servers certificate. In your case none of it's certificates which come with client software can verify the server. Because it is the clients jobs to verify the server, and if a server certificate verification request isn't sent (usually isn't) then you can choose to proceed with the connection.

Comment: This thread is about adding custom certificates, auto generating certificates, perhaps you can figure out the certificate signing authority and provide it to the client. https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/347